# Global import variables and IIFEs

Tags: javascript

A number of different articles around the web have been professing the greatness of using global import when designing modules (similiar to jQuery).

So, doing something like this...

```
(function(globalVariable){
  globalVariable.printStuff = function(){
    console.log(‘Hello World’)
  };
}(globalVariable));
```

...means that I can call a function with something like this:

```
globalVariable.printStuff();
```

The problem is, whenever I run this in the console, I keep getting:

```
globalVariable undefined
```

My quesiton is, where exactly do I need to declare this variable so that I can get this to work?

Comment: What's up with `globalVariable.printStuff(){ /* what is this even? */};`?

Comment: while its not the solution, be careful of curly quotes `‘Hello World’` you should be using regular quotes `'`. Also, are you actually defining a variable called `globalVariable` that you're passing in to your IIFE?

Comment: I want all of the functions within this function to not pollute the global namespace and minimize conflicts with other scripts. So, I was hoping that having something like globalVariable will enable me to target those private functions.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the original code.. it's meant to be `globalVariable.printStuff = function()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a real simple module, you don't need any IIFE. Just write an object literal:

```
var globalVariable = {
    printStuff: function() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }
};

globalVariable.printStuff();
```

If you want to use an IIFE scope, you still have to create the object somewhere. That could be inside the module or outside:

```
var globalVariable = (function() {
     var module = {};
     var localVariable = 'Hello World';
     module.printStuff = function() {
         console.log(localVariable);
     };
     return module;
}());

globalVariable.printStuff();
```

```
var globalVariable = {};

(function(module) {
     var localVariable = 'Hello World';
     module.printStuff = function() {
         console.log(localVariable);
     };
}(globalVariable));

globalVariable.printStuff();
```

Comment: That's it! I was trying to declare the globalVariable as `var globalVariable;`.  Why does it need to defined as an object?

Comment: Because you want to create properties on it…

Comment: Of course :) Makes sense now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

For a browser [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object is the object that stores all the global variables. Below code shows a basic implementation of IIFEs with global variable.

```js
//Set a variable 'globalVariable' in the window object
window.globalVariable = 10;

//Access the global variable 'globalVariable' in IIFE
(function(globalVariable) {
console.log(globalVariable);
})(globalVariable);
```

Comment: Why would I want to do this?

Comment: My intention was to explain you how global variables work in JavaScript using IIFE